# how to set multiple default button in form by javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have two DIV called dvCreate and dvLogin, and inside each of which is a submit button (btnCreate and btnLogin).

I want fire click event of btnLogin when press Enter key inside the dvLogin and rise event click of btnCreate when press Enter key inside the dvCreate.

```
<div class="box-authentication" id="dvCreate">
     <input id="emmail_register" name="emmail_register" type="text" class="form-control">              
     <button type="submit" id="btnCreate" class="button" name="submit" value="create">Create User</button>
  </div>

<div class="box-authentication" id="dvLogin">
     <input id="emmail_register" name="emmail_register" type="text" class="form-control">              
     <button type="submit" id="btnLogin" class="button" name="submit" value="create">Login Usre</button>
 </div>
```

how to handle this by javascript ot jquery?

Comment: Provided you fix your html so that your login button has a value of `login`, not create, when the form submits, your backend will get a form value for `submit` of either create/login.  Given that, do you really need to turn enter presses into clicks?

Comment: If you have to submit but don't want to navigate away from the page, look into JQuery's ajaxSubmit method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('#dvCreate').addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    if(event.key==='Enter'){
      event.preventDefault();
      eventHandlerOfDvLogin()
    }  
});

document.querySelector('#dvLogin').addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    if(event.key==='Enter'){
      event.preventDefault();
      eventHandlerOfDvCreate()
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#dvCreate").keypress(function (e) {
            if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
                $('#btnCreate').click();

            }

    });
        $("#dvlogin").keypress(function (e) {

            if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {

                 $('#btnLogin').click();
            }

                });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make both of those divs forms instead, and then control the form with jquery `$('#dvLogin').submit(function(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); /* rest of your code here */ })`

That way, the form is submitted whether you press the button or press enter on the input, and you run whatever code you want in that section above `/* */`